# How to verify if $g$ is a generator for $p$?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, elgamal-encryption

For learning purpose, supposed I have a 16-digit prime which is $2685735182215187$, how do I verify if $g$ is a generator? ($p$ is supposedly a special kind of prime)

Comment: The special kind of prime that you have is called a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime). it's a prime of the form $p = 2q + 1$ where $q$ is also prime (as shown by poncho's answer).

Comment: @puzzlepalace sorry, I'm still confused about q. Where do I actually get the q?

Comment: You can derive $q$ from $p$. In other words, to check if $p$ is a safe prime, you check if $q  = \frac{p-1}{2}$ is also prime.

Comment: @puzzlepalace Thank you for your swift reply. I have computed and checked q=(p-1)/2 and my program returns true (it is indeed a prime). So I'm safe to say that q is also a prime, which means that p is a special kind of prime.

Comment: @puzzlepalace However, I'm still confused about g. I have computed g^(p-1)/2 mod p and g^p-1/(p-1/2) like what poncho has mentioned. The first output is 1342867591052455, and the second output is 0. I'm a little confused about these numbers, do they mean that g is a generator?

Comment: @puzzlepalace I made a mistake, power function doesn't work like math in Java. The output is 0 and 4. So I am safe to say g is a generator for p?

Answer (score 9):

Steps:

- Factor $p-1$, that is, find the primes which, multiplied together, produce $p-1$.  In your case, $2685735182215186 = 2 \times 1342867591107593$
- For each prime factor $q$ of $p-1$, verify that $g^{(p-1)/q} \not\equiv 1\pmod p$

If every such $q$ verifies (that is, they were all not 1), then $g$ is a generator.

Comment: Hey @poncho thanks. I do not understand "For each prime factor q of p−1, verify that g(p−1)/q≢1(mod p)" Is there anyway you can explain it simpler?

Comment: @Ken: Compute $g^{2685735182215186/2} \bmod p$.  Compute $g^{2685735182215186/1342867591107593} \bmod p$.  If they are both something other than 1, then $g$ is a generator

Comment: @Ken: Java's `long` type has 64 bits; it's not going to be able to store $2^{1342867591107593}$ without wrapping around. You will need to either switch to BigIntegers (in which case you really should use [`BigInteger::modPow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger))) or implement a [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) algorithm yourself.

Comment: @Ken: alternatively, if you're just looking for a generator, well, $g=2$ works for your specific modulus...

Comment: @poncho I have gotten outputs of 0 and 4. So it's safe to say that g is a generator for p?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thank you, I've just noticed that. What a mistake. I'm so sorry. I've gotten outputs of 0 and 4 now. Thank you.

Comment: @poncho my tutorial is asking me to verify if g = 2 is a generator for p, so I have to stick with g = 2, but need to verify if it is generator for p.

Comment: What if factoring $p - 1$ is unfeasible? Is it then impossible to verify or are there other techniques you can apply?

Comment: If factoring $p-1$ is infeasible, then I don't know of a way to be absolutely certain.  However, if $g$ and $p$ were generated nonmaliciously, then it would be able to be able to determine it with a high likelihood of correctness, just by using the factors of $p-1$ you can compute; the probability that, for a random $g$, that $g^{(p-1)/q} \equiv 1$ is $1/q$, which is tiny for the large prime factors

Answer (score 8):

In general, proving that $g$ is a primitive root (often called a generator) of a cyclic group is fairly simple. *Note this holds true for non prime modulo as well*

**Step 1:**

Verify that $0\leqslant g \lt p$ and $(g,p)=1$

In other words, verify that $g$ is less than p but greater than or equal to 0, and that $g$ and $p$ are coprime.

Where $g$ is the element of the group in question and p is the modulus being used (or: $\mathbb{Z}_p$).

**Step 2:**

Calculate $\phi(p)$ where $\phi$ is the Totient Function. If it happens that $p$ is prime, $\phi(p)=p-1$

Then break $\phi(p)$ into it's prime factors such that $\phi(p)=\prod\limits_{i}q_i^{r_i}$ Where each $q_i$ is a prime factor and $r_i$ is the power that prime factor is raised to.

*(This notation simply implies that $\phi(p)$ is to be broken down into it's prime factors $q_i$ such that $\phi(p)=q_1^{r_1}\times q_2^{r_2}\times ...$)*

Verify that $g^{\phi(p)/q_i}\not\equiv 1 (mod p)$ $\forall q_i$

Ignore the power $r_i$ for this calculation.

Assuming these conditions are met, $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

---

**Example:**

Let $p=101$, $g=2$.

*Step 1:*

$0\leqslant 2 \lt 101$ $\checkmark$

and

$(2,101) = 1$ $\checkmark $

Which can be checked using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) if $p$ is not prime (however, 101 is prime, so 2 is most definitely coprime to it).

*Step 2*

Calculate $\phi(p)=p-1=\phi(101)=101-1=100$ (Assuming $p$ is prime).

Now that we know $\phi(101)=100$, we can break it down into it's prime factors. Check that:

$100=2^2\times5^2$

This means that our $q_1=2, q_2=5$. Remember that we ignore the powers $r_i$ of each of the prime factors for our computations.

Finally, we check:

$2^{\phi(101)/q_1}=2^{(101-1)/2}=2^{50}\equiv100\not\equiv1(mod 101)\checkmark$
$2^{\phi(101)/q_2}=2^{(101-1)/5}=2^{20}\equiv95\not\equiv1(mod 101)\checkmark$

$\therefore g$ is a generator $mod 101$.

(Read: therefore $g$ is a generator $mod 101$.)

Note that this process is to be done $\forall q_i$, in our case there were only two.

(Read: note that this process is to be done for all $q_i$...)

---

In your example, and in practical examples, $p$ is very large. First, confirming that $p$ is prime can be difficult. Second, factorizing $\phi(p)$ into it's prme factors can be quite difficult. I recommend implementing an algorithm to help you, such as [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) (although there are others that'll work, like [trivial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division)).

Comment: Hi @TryingToPassCollege, thank you so much. However, could you give an example? For learning purpose, for example, p = 2685735182104907 and g = 2.. I understand from Step 1 that from the looks of my p and g, it is definitely between 0 and p, and they are definitely coprime because I made a primality check on Java, and p is a prime. As such, g = 2, is a coprime as well. From step 2 onwards, I'm a little confused because tbh I don't understand most of the symbols. I feel like I'm lacking a lot of mathematics experience.. So sorry for all the trouble, as I don't have anyone else to turn to.

Comment: @Ken I have added an example, a few *read as* descriptions to explain the symbols, and a small summary about applying this method if $p$ is large. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that non-prime modulii (specially, ones with two distinct odd prime factors) do not have generators; that is, there is no element $g$ where $g^x \bmod n$ is all members of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$

Answer (score 4):

$p = 2685735182215187$ is prime, and $p - 1 = 2q$ where $q = 1342867591107593$ is prime, so the only possible orders of $g$ are $\{1, 2, q, 2q\}$, corresponding respectively to

- $g \equiv 1 \pmod p$,
- $g \equiv -1 \pmod p$,
- $g$ is a nontrivial quadratic residue modulo $p$, *i.e.* there is some $h \notin \{0,\pm1\}$ such that $g \equiv h^2 \pmod p$, and
- $g$ is a nontrivial quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$, which in this case generates the whole group.

If $g$ is neither $1$ nor $-1$, it suffices to compute the Legendre symbol of $g$, $$(g|p) := g^{(p - 1)/2} \bmod p = g^q \bmod p,$$ which is 1 if $g$ is a quadratic residue and 0 or -1 if it is not.  Obviously you can compute $g^q \bmod p$ directly, as in poncho's answer which applies more generally, but **for many values of $g$, there are special cases which you can test much more easily by the quadratic reciprocity theorem**, that, for distinct odd primes $a$ and $b$, $(a|b) = -(b|a)$ if $a \equiv b \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, whereas $(a|b) = (b|a)$ if either $a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $b \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

- $3 \equiv p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so $(3|p) = -(p|3) = -p^{(3 - 1)/2} \bmod 3 = -p^1 \bmod 3 = 1$, so **3 is a quadratic residue and thus is *not* a generator of the whole group.**
- $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so $(5|p) = (p|5) = p^{(5 - 1)/2} \bmod 5 = p^2 \bmod 5 = 4 \bmod 5 = -1$, so **5 is a quadratic nonresidue and thus *is* a generator of the whole group.**
- The second supplement to the quadratic reciprocity theorem is that $g = 2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$.  In this case, $p \equiv 3 \pmod 8$, so **2 is a quadratic nonresidue and thus *is* a generator of the whole group.**

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a bit more details to quickly justify the algorithm given by Tyler:

1. Decompose $\phi(p)$ ( $= p-1$ if $p$ is prime) in product of prime factors: $\phi(p) = q_1^{r_1}…q_n^{r_n}$
2. For all $i$, check that $g^{\phi(p)/{q_i}} \neq 1$
3. If yes, $g$ is a generator, otherwise it's not.

this can be justified using the Lagrange's theorem (that tells you that the order (=size) of a sub-group must divide the order of the group).

More precisely, let $x$ be the order of the subgroup generated by $g$. Then, the order of the subgroup generated by $g$ is the smaller $x$ such that $g^x = 1$. But the order of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is $\phi(p)$ (equals $p-1$ when $p$ is prime), so Lagrange's theorem tells you that $x$ divides $\phi(p)$. However, to check that $g$ is a generator you do not need to check that $g^x \neq 1$ for all $x$ divisors of $\phi(p)$, you only need to check that for the **largest divisors** of $\phi(p)$. Indeed, if $q$ divides $r$ (i.e. there exists $k$ such that $q = kr$) and if $g^q = 1$, then $g^r = (g^q)^k = 1^k = 1$… Said differently, if it's $\neq 1$ for the bigger ones, then it's also $\neq 1$ for the smaller (it term of division) dividers.

To get these largest divisors, you just need to take $\phi(p)$ and remove (=divide) each time a different prime factor. You can easily get convinced on a picture (here taking $p = 13$, so $\phi(p) = p-1 = 12$), the proof is not too hard:

[image]

(pardon my dirty quick diagram)

So for $p = 13$ you would only need to check that $g^4 \neq 1 \mod 13$ and $g^6 \neq 1 \mod 13$ to check that $p$ is a prime.

**Further optimization**: to compute $g^x$, it's quicker to use the square and multiply (or decompose $x$ appropriately) than computing $g \times … \times g$ (otherwise the above optimization would not be really interesting).